# Understanding Array.ConvertAll, can I DirectCast?

Tags: vb.net, typeconverter

I have a base class, DtaRow, that has an internal array of Strings containing data. I have dozens of subclasses of DtaRow, like UnitRow and AccountRow, who's only purpose is to provide Properties to retrieve the values, so you can do `aUnit.Name` instead of `aUnit.pFields(3)`.

I also have a DtaTable object that contains a `Friend pRows As New Dictionary(Of Integer, DtaRow)`. I don't generally insert DtaRows into the DtaTable, I insert the subclasses like UnitRows and AccountRows. Any given table has only one type in it.

Over in the main part of the app I have an accessor:

```
Public Readonly Property Units() As IEnumerable
    Get
        Return Tables(5).pRows.Values 'oh oh oh oh table 5, table 5...
    End Get
End Property
```

This, obviously, returns a list of DtaRows, not UnitRows, which means I can't do `MyDB.Units(5).Name`, which is the ultimate goal.

The obvious solution is to `Dim ret As New UnitRow()` and DirectCast everything into it, but then I'm building thousands of new arrays all the time. Uggg. Alternately I could put DirectCast everywhere I pull out a value, also uggg.

I see there is a method called Array.ConvertAll that looks like it might be what I want. But maybe that just does the loop for me and doesn't really save anything? And if this is what I want, I don't really understand how to use DirectCast in it.

Hopefully I'm just missing some other bit of API that does what I want, but failing that, what's the best solution here? I suspect I need...

- to make a widening conversion in each DtaRow subclass?
- or something in DtaTable that does the same?

Comment: Different solution? It seems the real problem here is that I declared the container to be Dictionary(of Integer, DtaRow). It should **not** say DtaRow should it? It should say <SomeSortofPlaceholderThatWillBeFilledInLater>, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ConvertAll to convert an array into a different type.

```
    Dim arr(2) As A
    Dim arr2() As B

    arr(0) = New B
    arr(1) = New B
    arr(2) = New B

    arr2 = Array.ConvertAll(arr, Function(o) DirectCast(o, B))

Class A

End Class

Class B
    Inherits A

End Class
```

In your case, I think it would look like this

```
Return Array.ConvertAll(Tables(5).pRows.Values, Function(o) DirectCast(o, UnitRow))
```

Note that this will create a new array each time.

Comment: This did work - it's the `Function (o)` part I wasn't getting right. But if this does create a new array every time, that's not a **good** solution. Perhaps there is a completely different way to approach this?

Comment: I take that back. Error 29 Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of Integer, SFImporterDLL.DtaRow).ValueCollection' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of SFImporterDLL.DtaRow' Multiple attempts to solve this have failed. I do not understand this concept well enough to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the objects into a `list(Of String)` based on the field you want.

```
Return Tables(5).pRows.Values.Cast(Of DtaRow).Select(Function(r) r.name).ToList
```

Comment: (edit) Uhhhh, I'm not sure this solves the problem. The goal is `MyDB.Units(5).Name`, and if I return a generic list of strings I lose that. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Not sure what your after. Thought you needed a collection of the names.

Comment: All things `Lambda` or `LINQ` use an internal loop - can't get away from that. Most of us like the readability of the query/expression.

Comment: Ok, so is there some totally different way I should be approaching this? The objects in the collection really are UnitRows, so how do I get a list of UnitRows back, forget conversions or that, how would you go about doing this? Subclass DtaTable and change the data type in the array? Surely there must be some generic solution to "collection that might have subclasses in it", or you seem to be defeating the entire idea of subclasses!

Comment: If `DtaRows` is the base class then you can retrieve objects that derive from it. If the collection is a derived class(subclass) then this `Cast` will still work.

Comment: You can add `UnitRows` in a collection of `DtaRows`. You will need to convert the objects if they have a non-inherited property that you want.

Comment: If you could share the class structures it may help to see what your doing.

Comment: It's basically identical to what lotus has below. The only difference is that my Dim arr is inside another class, the DtaTable. But I suspect **that's** the root problem, right, that I should not declare the original array as holding A's, but some sort of "A or a subclass I'll tell you about when I create you". I know that is a basic part of .net's generics, but I've never actually used it.

Answer (score 0):

YES! I went non-linear. This only works because of OOP...

My ultimate goal was to return objects from the collection as a particular type, because I knew I put that type in there in the first place. Sure, I could get the value out of the collection and CType it, but that's fugly - although in C# I would have been perfectly happy because the syntax is nicer.

So wait... the method that retrieves the row from the collection is *in the collection class*, not the various subclasses of DtaRow. So here is what I did...

```
Public ReadOnly Property Units() As IEnumerable
    Get
        Return Tables(dbTblUnits).pRow.Values
    End Get
End Property
Public ReadOnly Property Units(ByVal K as Integer) As UnitRow
    Get
        Return DirectCast(Tables(dbTblUnits)(K), UnitRow)
    End Get
End Property
Public ReadOnly Property Units(ByVal K as String) As UnitRow
    Get
        Return DirectCast(Tables(dbTblUnits).Rows(K), UnitRow)
    End Get
End Property
```

Why does this solve the problem? Well normally if one does...

```
Dim U as UnitRow = MyDB.Units(K)
```

It would call the first method (which is all I had originally) which would return the .Values from the Dictionary, and then the Default Property would be called to return .Item(K). But because of the way the method dispatcher works, if I provide a more specific version that more closely matches the parameters, it will call that. So I provide overrides that are peers to the subclasses that do the cast.

Now this isn't perfect, because if I just call Units to get the entire list, when I pull rows out of it I'll still have to cast them. But people *expect* that, so this is perfectly acceptable in this case. Better yet, when I open this DLL in VBA, only the first of these methods is visible, which returns the entire collection, which means that Units(k) will call the Default Property on the DtaTable, returning a DtaRow, but that's fine in VBA.

OOP to the rescue!